# How can I find the collation of a column as I am getting different results depending upon where I look?

Tags: mysql

If I use `select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'countries';`, I see the COLLATION_NAME of `utf8_general_ci` for all the text columns.

If I use `show full columns from countries;`, I see COLLATION of `utf8_general_ci` for all the text columns, matching the above command's output.

If I use `show create table countries;`, I see the table with the COLLATION of `utf8_unicode_ci` and no collation on the columns.

The character set is `utf8`.

Prior to all of these commands, I've run :

```
ALTER TABLE countries
    CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET UTF8,
    COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
    ROW_FORMAT DYNAMIC,
    CHANGE COLUMN `code` `code` char(2) CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL  COMMENT '',
    CHANGE COLUMN `name` `name` varchar(80) CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL  COMMENT ''
;
```

and so I'm expecting `utf8_unicode_ci` everywhere.

But this seems to make no difference to values stored in information_schema.columns

The goal is to convert my entire DB to `utf8_unicode_ci`, but at around 60GB I don't want to waste time in converting things I don't need to do.

How do I determine if the column is already in the correct collation, when what I can tell is that the information_schema and the various column describing mechanisms all say it is in the wrong collation when compared to the `show create table` command?

Answer (score 0):

It seems attempting to alter the collation of both the columns and the table in the same query, regardless of order, doesn't work and only the table collation is altered.